# Хранение ArrayList в файле настроек SharedPreferences

Tags: android, java, массивы

Всем добрый день.
В процессе разработки некоего приложения, возникла необходимость создания корзины для товаров, в которой должно храниться id товара, цена и описание. Так вот для этих целей написал свой класс, который поместил в ArrayList, то есть:

```
public final List<MyObject> basket = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

Теперь встал вопрос о том как же сделать, чтобы товары помещенные в нее не исчезали после перезапуска прилоежния, и на ум пришло одно - файлы настроек.
Так вот столкнувшись с этим я понял, что не знаю как туда впихнуть ArrayList, а повнимательнее посмотрев- понял, что это вовсе невозможно!

Вопрос: как это сделать, или может есть другие варианты для организации оффлайн корзины в приложении?

Comment: Для подобных целей используйте sqlite.

Comment: Напишите для вашего класса MyObject преобразования в строку и обратно. Тогда в настройках можно будет сохранять как одну строку.

Comment: То есть тупо toString()? А как обратно? Или Вы имеете в виду Google-GSON?

Comment: если умеете json - делайте json. Но может Ваш MyObject внутри по факту хранит только одно целое число (а все остальное можно вытянуть с других мест и восстановить). Тогда можно просто как последовательность чисел сохранить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да можно воткнуть в префы. Переведите вашу корзину в JSON строку и храните на здоровье строку в префах.

Другие варианты:

- есть еще БД SQLite
- можно тупо кинуть в бинарном формате в приватный каталог приложения `Context.getFilesDir()`

**Update:** Пример работы с JSON через Google GSon:

В строку:

```
  MyClass myObject;
  String s=new Gson().toJson(myObject, MyClass.class);
```

Из строки:

```
  MyClass myObject=new Gson().fromJson(s, MyClass.class);
```

Проще пареной репы.

Comment: В json строку через Google -GSON? А есть какие нить примеры по работе с ним?

Comment: см. апдейт

Comment: Ок спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Answer (score 4):

```
public void saveObject(String key, Object object) 
{
        Editor editor = preference.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        String jsonStr = gson.toJson(object);
        editor.putString(key, jsonStr);
        editor.commit();        
}

public ArrayList<?> loadList(String key, Class<?> class_) 
{

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();  
        String json = preference.getString(key, "");

        if (hStrings.isEmpty(json)) return arrayList;

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            arrayList.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i), class_));
        }

        return arrayList ;
}
```

где `preference = getSharedPreferences("MAIN_STORAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
hStrings.isEmpty(String) - проверяем на пустую строку (свой метод)

Использование

Сохранение :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filterList  = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

          ....заполнение clickFilterList....
```

saveObject("filterList", filterList);

Получение :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clickFilterList = 
(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)loadList("filterList", HashMap.class);
```